# Slowly turn a string into another

Tags: code-golf, string

### The Challenge

Given two strings/an array of strings, output the first string slowly shrinking and expanding back into the second string.

You can assume the strings will always start with the same character.

### Example

```
Input:
"Test", "Testing"

Output:
Test
Tes
Te
T
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing
```

First you output the first word:

```
Test
```

Then you keep removing one letter until the string is one character long:

```
Tes
Te
T
```

Then keep adding one letter of the second word until it's done:

```
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing
```

(if both strings are one character long, then just output one of them once.)

### Test Cases

```
"Hello!", "Hi."
Hello!
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
Hi
Hi.

"O", "O"

O

"z", "zz"

z
zz

".vimrc", ".minecraft"

.vimrc
.vimr
.vim
.vi
.v
.
.m
.mi
.min
.mine
.minec
.minecr
.minecra
.minecraf
.minecraft

"     ", "   "

SSSSS
SSSS
SSS
SS
S
SS
SSS

"0123456789", "02468"

0123456789
012345678
01234567
0123456
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
02
024
0246
02468
```

*(note: on the space/fourth test case, replace the S with spaces)*

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins! Tiebreaker is most upvoted post. Winner will be chosen on 09/10/2016.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: Will 2 trailing newlines (one visible empty line after the sequence) be allowed or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
j+_._Et._
```

A program that takes the second string, and then the first string, as quoted strings on STDIN and prints the result.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B_._Et._&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Hi.%22%0A%22Hello%21%22%0A%22O%22%0A%22O%22%0A%22zz%22%0A%22z%22%0A%22.minecraft%22%0A%22.vimrc%22%0A%22+++%22%0A%22+++++%22%0A%2202468%22%0A%220123456789%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

**How it works**

```
j+_._Et._  Program. Inputs: Q, E
   ._E     Yield prefixes of E as a list
  _        Reverse the above
       ._  Yield prefixes of Q as a list (implicit input fill)
      t    All but the first element of above
 +         Merge the two lists
j          Join on newlines
           Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 14):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 14 bytes

```
òYp$xhòjòÄ$xhh
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w7JZcCR4aMOyasOyw4QkeGho&input=MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQowMjQ2OA)

Explanation:

```
ò     ò     "Recursively:
 Yp         "  Yank the current line and paste it
   $        "  Move to the end of the current line
    x       "  Delete one character
     h      "  Move One character to the right.
            "  Because of the way loops work in V, this will throw an error if there
            "  Is only one character on the current line.
```

Now, the buffer looks like this:

```
0123456789
012345678
01234567
0123456
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

We just need to do the same thing in reverse for the next line:

```
j           "Move down one line
 ò     ò    "Recursively (The second ò is implicit)
  Ä         "  Duplicate this line up
   $        "  Move to the end of the current line
    x       "  Delete one character
     hh     "  Move two characters to the right.
            "  Because of the way loops work in V, this will throw an error if there
            "  Is only two characters on the current line.
```

[More interesting alternate solution](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w7LDhCR4aMOyw6deLzptMApkZEdwQHFk&input=MDEyMzQ1Njc4OQowMjQ2OA):

```
òÄ$xhòç^/:m0
ddGp@qd
```

Comment: It is like vim is always correct tool for job

Comment: @Downgoat Exactly. That's why *you* need to start golfing in V. :P

Answer (score 9):

## Python, 93 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,r='',i=2:a and f(a[:-1],b,r+a+'\n')or(len(b)>=i and f(a,b,r+b[:i]+'\n',i+1)or r)
```

Starts with the empty string `r`, adds `a` and a newline and removes the last character from `a` until `a` is empty then adds the required portions of `b` and a newline by keeping a counter, `i`, which starts at `2` until the length of `b` is exceeded, then returns `r`. Has a trailing newline.

All tests are on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/fjXSMI)

Comment: 2 things. 1) I believe that you miscounted characters and it is actually 93 and 2) You don't need to say `r=""`. Simple `r` would still work.

Comment: Thanks @JackBates. 1. Correct, and updated - I probably forgot the `f=`. 2. Without the `r=''` present `f('test','testing')` would not work; yes `f('test','testing','')` would, but we must follow the specifications.

Comment: Forgive me. I was just looking at the code and not the examples.

Answer (score 7):

## Retina, <s>50</s> <s>41</s> 26 bytes

Thanks to Martin Ender for saving 15(!) bytes.

```
M&!r`.+
Om`^.¶[^·]+|.+
A1`
```

Takes input with the two strings separated by a newline:

```
Test
Testing
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TSYhcmAuKwpPbWBeLsK2W17Ct10rfC4rCkExYA&input=VGVzdApUZXN0aW5n)

### Explanation

```
M&!r`.+
```

The first line generates the "steps" of both words:

```
Testing
Testin
Testi
Test
Tes
Te
T
Test
Tes
Te
T
```

`M` is for match mode, `&` considers overlapping matches, and `!` prints the matches instead of the number of them. The reason it's reversed is the `r`ight-to-left option: the engine starts looking for matches at the end of the string and continues toward the beginning.

```
Om`^.¶[^·]+|.+
```

This gets everything in the right order: it s`O`rts all matches of the subsequent regex: A character on its own line and every character (including newlines) after it, which matches the whole second half as one chunk, or otherwise a line of characters, which matches each individual line. These matches are then sorted by code point, so the T followed by the newline goes first, followed by the lines, ascending by length.

```
A1`
```

Now we just have that first character line on top so we use `A`ntigrep mode to discard the first match of the default regex `.+`.

### Old version

```
M&!r`.+
O`\G..+¶
s`(.*)¶.¶(.*)
$2¶$1
¶.$
```

[Try this version online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TSYhcmAuKwpPYFxHLi4rwrYKc2AoLiopwrYuwrYoLiopCiQywrYkMQrCti4kCg&input=VGVzdApUZXN0aW5n)

#### Explanation

The first line is the same, so see the explanation for that above.

```
O`\G..+¶
```

This reverses the lines of the first half (second input word). It actually s`O`rts the lines, and the regex limits the matches: it must be a line of two or more characters (`..+`) followed by a newline (`¶`) that begins where the last one left off (`\G`). In the above example, the single `T` in the middle doesn't match, so nothing after it can.

```
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing
T
Test
Tes
Te
T
```

Now we have the right two components, but in the wrong order.

```
s`(.*)¶.¶(.*)
$2¶$1
```

`¶.¶` matches the lone T in the middle, which we don't need but separates the two parts. The two `(.*)` capture everything before and after, including newlines thanks to `s`ingle-line mode. The two captures are substituted in the right order with a newline in between.

Now we're done, unless the input strings are one character long, in which case the input hasn't changed. To get rid of the duplicate, we replace `¶.$` (when the last line of the string a single character) with nothing.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
.pRI.p¦«»
```

**Explanation**

```
.pR           # prefixes of first word
     I.p       # prefixes of second word
         ¦       # remove first prefix
          «     # concatenate
           »    # join with newlines
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnBSSS5wwqbCq8K7&input=VGVzdApUZXN0aW5n)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>88</s> 82 bytes

```
x,y=input(),input()
for i in x:print x;x=x[:-1]
s=y[0]
for i in y[1:]:s+=i;print s
```

Takes two inputs, each surrounded by quotes.

Thanks @JonathanAllan for saving some bytes and pointing out a bug.

Comment: No need for the `len(x)` in `x=x[:len(x)-1]` since negative offset slicing works - you can just write `x=x[:-1]`. Only problem is your code wont handle the `"     ", "   "` test case very well.

Comment: You can drop the second `input()` and use an input format like `"<str1>", "<str2>"`

Comment: You could change the second line to `for i in range(x):print x[-i:]`, and the fourth line to `for i in range(1,y):print y[:-i]`. Not sure it would work, though.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>34</s> 28 bytes

Includes `+2` for `-0n`

Run with the strings on separate lines on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.010 -0n slow.pl
Test
Testing
^D
```

`slow.pl`:

```
/(^..+|
\K.+?)(?{say$&})^/
```

Let regex backtracking do the work...

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>102</s> <s>97</s> <s>95</s> 93 bytes

```c
n;f(char*a,char*b){for(n=strlen(a);n;puts(a))a[n--]=0;for(a=b+1;*a++;*a=n)n=*a,*a=0,puts(b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsMgDET3fEXEZAJI6Wz5L7pFGQxK0kitWwGdqn47BaR6sE@n87vgjhBKEdwh3DhObPvx@rM/IwilHO@bAGsUfL1zqkrzIs6tNGOLMHlzwYmNqYtEC1VGVbPtca/xWxpy5GUldd1SVnYY2/i/ccqhcHjwKVBrgW1/@gE)

The first loop overwrites the string with 0 bytes starting from the end, and uses `puts()` to print the string. The second loop can't just overwrite from the beginning, it has to store the old value so it can put it back; the 0 byte is just walking towards the end.

Thanks to @homersimpson and @ceilingcat for each shaving off 2 bytes!

Comment: You can save a couple bytes by declaring `n` as a global int like: `n;f(char*a,char*b){n=strlen(a)...`. And you can probably do `n=*a=0` as a chained assignment in the body of your for loop.

Comment: Thanks @homersimpson. But n=*a=0 is not the same as n=*a,*a=0.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 104 bytes

Meh.

```meh
n='\n';lambda x,y:x+n+n.join(x[:-i]for i in range(1,len(x)-1))+n+n.join(y[:i]for i in range(1,len(y)+1))
```

Thanks to @DJMcMayhem for golfing 21 bytes off.

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/BNlGzA)

Comment: You can take 5 bytes of if you do `n='\n'` and use *n* instead of `'\n'`. You could take another 8 off if you used a lambda instead of printing: `n='\n';lambda x,y:n.join(x+n+n.join(x[:-i]for i in range(1,len(x)-1))+n+n.join(y[:i]for i in range(1,len(y)+1)))`

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <strike>103</strike> 81 bytes

```
f=(x,y,n=1)=>x?`
`+x+f(x.slice(0,-1),y):n++<y.length?`
`+y.slice(0,n)+f(x,y,n):''
```

Example: `f("Test", "Testing")`

Output:

```
Test
Tes
Te
T
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing
```

Original answer

```
f=(x,y,n=1)=>x?(console.log(x),f(x.slice(0,-1),y)):n++<y.length?(console.log(y.slice(0,n)),f(x,y,n)):''
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org), 76 bytes

```
(a,b,q=s->(|>s.len).map((_,i)->s.head(i+1)))->(q(a).rev+q(b).slice(1)).vfuse
```

A bit longer than I'd liked. I'll add an explanation soon

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=bGV0IGY9IChhLGIscT1zLT4ofD5zLmxlbikubWFwKChfLGkpLT5zLmhlYWQoaSsxKSkpLT4ocShhKS5yZXYrcShiKS5zbGljZSgxKSkudmZ1c2U7CgpzLT5mKHMubGluZXNbMF0sIHMubGluZXNbMV0p&input=SGVsbG8KSGku)

Comment: What does `|>` do?

Comment: @Cyoce unary |> is range [0,n) binary is [a,b]

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 32 bytes

```
:1aLtT,Lhbr:Tc~@nw
:2fb
~c[A:B]h
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjFhTHRULExoYnI6VGN-QG53CjoyZmIKfmNbQTpCXWg&input=WyJIZWxsbyEiOiJIaS4iXQ)

#### Explanation

Brachylog has no prefix built-in, therefore we will get the prefixes by using `concatenate` (See predicate 2): a prefix of `S` is `P` if `P` concatenated to `Q` (whatever it is) results in `S`.

- Main predicate:

  ```
  :1aL                  L is all prefixes of both elements of the input (see predicate 1)
     LtT,               T is the second element of L
         Lhbr           Remove the first prefix of the first list of L and reverse it
             :Tc        Concatenate with T
                ~@n     Join with newlines
                   w    Write to STDOUT
  ```
- Predicate 1:

  ```
  :2f                   Find all prefixes of the input string (see predicate 2)
     b                  Remove the first one (empty string)
  ```
- Predicate 2:

  ```
  ~c[A:B]               Input is the result of concatenating A to B
         h              Output is A
  ```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
VDO)KKQlFh<)_X
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=VDO%29KKQlFh%3C%29_X&input=Testing%0ATest&warnings=0)

And 17 bytes just because it's an awesome solution:

```
mVDO)Fto!I_O(RKsX
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=mVDO%29Fto%21I_O%28RKsX&input=%5B%22Test%22%2C%22Testing%22%5D)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>188</s> 179 bytes

```
interface E{static void main(String[]a){int i=a[0].length();while(i>1)System.out.println(a[0].substring(0,i--));while(i<=a[1].length())System.out.println(a[1].substring(0,i++));}}
```

**Update**

- Removed s variable, saved 9 bytes

**Ungolfed**:

```
interface E {

    static void main(String[] a) {
        int i = a[0].length();
        while (i > 1) {
            System.out.println(a[0].substring(0, i--));
        }
        while (i <= a[1].length()) {
            System.out.println(a[1].substring(0, i++));
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$ java E 'test' 'testing'
test
tes
te
t
te
tes
test
testi
testin
testing
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 47 bytes

```
t[]=[]
t x=x:t(init x)
(.reverse.t).(++).init.t
```

Usage example: `((.reverse.t).(++).init.t) "Hello" "Hi!"` -> `["Hello","Hell","Hel","He","H","Hi","Hi!"]`.

Some pointfree magic. It's the same as `f x y = (init(t x))++reverse (t y)` where `t` makes a list of all initial substrings e.g. `t "HI!"` -> `["H","HI","HI!"]`.

Comment: Hm, `t=reverse.tail.inits`?

Comment: @Bergi: sure, but `inits` needs `import Data.List`.

Answer (score 3):

### GNU sed, <s>57</s> 45 + 2(rn flags) = 47 bytes

```
:;1{/../p};2G;2h;s/.(\n.*)?$//;/./t;g;s/.$//p
```

**Run:**

```sh
echo -e "Test\nTesting" | sed -rnf morphing_string.sed
```

The input should be the two strings separated by a newline. The code is run by sed for each line.

The loop `:` deletes one character from the end of the string iteratively. The output related to the first string is printed directly, except the first character: `1{/../p}`. The output for the second string is stored in hold space in reverse order (`2G;2h`) during deletion and printed at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [Floroid](https://github.com/TuukkaX/Floroid), 69 bytes

```
a,b=L.J
c=1
NZ(a)!=1:z(a);a=a[:-1]
z(a)
NZ(a)!=Z(b):c+=1;a=b[:c];z(a)
```

It's a start. Takes the input from STDIN.

### Testcases

```
Input: Test Testing
Output:
Test
Tes
Te
T
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing

Input: O O
Output: O
```

Answer (score 2):

## REPL/Javascript, 109 Bytes

Uses false string to whittle down the original string

Abuses substring with larger numbers to grow the second one, stops when its about to print the same word as last time.

```
(a,b)=>{l=console.log;z='substring';for(c=a.length;d=a[z](0,c--);){l(d)}for(c=2;d!=(n=b[z](0,c++));){l(d=n)}}
```

Demo:

```
> ((a,b)=>{l=console.log;z='substring';for(c=a.length;d=a[z](0,c--);){l(d)}for(c=2;d!=(n=b[z](0,c++));){l(d=n)}})("asdf","abcd")
[Log] asdf
[Log] asd
[Log] as
[Log] a
[Log] ab
[Log] abc
[Log] abcd
```

Comment: it's 1 byte shorter to do `a=>b=>...` and call the function with (a)(b)

Answer (score 2):

## Racket 193 bytes

```
(define(f l)
(let*((s(list-ref l 0))
(x(string-length s)))
(for((n x))
(println(substring s 0(- x n))))
(set! s(list-ref l 1))
(for((n(range 1(string-length s))))
(println(substring s 0(add1 n))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f(list "Test" "Testing"))

"Test"
"Tes"
"Te"
"T"
"Te"
"Tes"
"Test"
"Testi"
"Testin"
"Testing"


(f(list "Hello!" "Hi."))

"Hello!"
"Hello"
"Hell"
"Hel"
"He"
"H"
"Hi"
"Hi."
```

Comment: It should delete last character from input string, not the first one.

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck, <strike>38</strike> 55 bytes

```
>++++++++++>,[>,]<[<]>>[[.>]<[-]<[<]>.>],.[[<]>.>[.>],]
```

Edit: included newlines in output

Comment: I can't get your code to work. Is the input separated by a new line? Which interpreter are you using?

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>20</s> 13 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
↑(⌽,\⍞),1↓,\⍞
```

`↑` matrify

`(⌽,\⍞)` reversed (`⌽`) cumulative concatenation (`,\`) of character input (`⍞`)

`,` prepended to

`1↓` one element dropped from

`,\⍞` cumulative concatenation of character input

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2206%20%u2359%u2190%27Test%27%20%27Testing%27%20%u22C4%20%u2191%28%u233D%2C%5C%u2206%29%2C1%u2193%2C%5C%u2359&run)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
+↔ḣ²tḣ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/tR25SHOxYf2lQCJB81bvj//39IanEJmMjMSwcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
［］↕ｋ；［］∔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXUyMTk1JXVGRjRCJXVGRjFCJXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXUyMjE0,i=VGVzdCUwQVRlc3Rpbmc_,v=8)

Explanation:

```
[]↕k;[]+ | Full program (characters replaced for clean formatting)
---------+--------------------------------------------------------
[]       | Prefixes of first input
  ↕      | Reversed
   k     | Remove the last item
    ;    | Swap (places the second input on top)
     []  | Prefixes of second input
       + | Add vertically
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
€ƒẸrsḥ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMiU4MiVBQyVDNiU5MiVFMSVCQSVCOHJzJUUxJUI4JUE1JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyVGVzdGluZyUyMiUyQyUyMCUyMlRlc3QlMjImZmxhZ3M9Tg==)

Takes inputs in reverse order.

##### Explanation

```python
€ƒẸrsḥ  # Implicit input
€ƒ      # Prefixes of each
  Ẹr    # Dump and reverse
    sḥ  # Swap and concatenate
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 88 bytes (function) (92 for lambda) (beginner)

As lambda-function (92 bytes):

```
f=lambda A,B:"\n".join([(A+" ")[:-i]for i in range(len(A))]+[B[:i+1]for i in range(len(B))])
```

As function:

```
def f(a,b,c=""):
 while a!=b[0]and a:print(a);a=a[:-1]
 while b:c+=b[0];b=b[1:];print(c)
```

In code:  or 72 bytes (from 93 bytes)
Shall 'a' be the word to decrease an 'b' be the word to raise up to, this should do:

```
for i in range(len(a)+(a[0]!=b[0])):print((a+"_")[:-i])
for k in range(len(b)):print(b[:k+1])
```

or with 72 chars

```
c=""
while a!=b[0]and a:print(a);a=a[:-1]
while b:c+=b[0];b=b[1:];print(c)
```

Apart from the lambda-version my solutions will work even with the strings starting differently (overread that part o.0 )

Comment: You can't assume the input is in a variable.

Comment: So it must be a function? @daHugLenny

Comment: Either take input by STDIN (`input()`/`raw_input()`) or by function arguments. Also, instead of chars, count the length in [bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter).

Comment: pretty sure some people here count chars and claim bytes, but ok. Thanks @daHugLenny

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```
(s,t)=>s.replace(/./g,`
$\`$&`).split`
`.slice(2).reverse().join`
`+t.replace(/./g,`
$\`$&`)
```

The `replace` statements build up a triangle of strings, which is exactly what's required for the second half of the output, however the first half needs to be reversed and the duplicate single-character line removed. Note: outputs a leading newline if the first string is a single character. If this is undesirable then for an extra byte this version always outputs a trailing newline:

```
(s,t)=>s.replace(/./g,`
$\`$&\n`).split(/^/m).slice(1).reverse().join``+t.replace(/./g,`
$\`$&\n`)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 142 bytes

```
#define _(x,y) while(y)printf("%.*s\n",d,x-c);
f(char*a,char*b){int c=1,d=strlen(a)+1;while(*++a==*++b)c++;_(a,--d>=c)d++;_(b,d++<strlen(b-c))}
```

Provide `f(char* str1, char* str2)`.

Comment: [137 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY5BDsIgFET3PUWDm/8FmnSNeJUGPqAkthqK2qbp2ZE0bmY2M/OG5I2olJPzIU6@HWARK4ZnAse5WtXrnWdgDPGbYvbQi0WScKiaqioA3U06G3GYxY10r46unnN6@AkMqjPnRuuqViHVzQGMcFJeCQewolIu/6yVhLiX0cQJcGvaAKz7xDEREy3rxvqOkgmZVfhefg "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 56 bytes

```
Prompt Str1,Str2
Str1
While 1<length(Ans
Disp Ans
sub(Ans,1,length(Ans)-1
End
For(I,1,length(Str2
Disp sub(Str2,1,I
End
```

**Example usage**

```
Str1=?Test
Str2=?Testing
Test
Tes
Te
T
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing

Str1=?O
Str2=?O
O

Str1=?z
Str2=?zz
z
zz
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>168</s> 136 bytes

```
(s,d)->{int i=s.length()+1;while(i-->1)System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));while(i++<d.length())System.out.println(d.substring(0,i));};
```

## Ungolfed test program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BiConsumer<String, String> biconsumer = (s, d) -> {
        int i = s.length() + 1;
        while (i-- > 1) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));
        }
        while (i++ < d.length()) {
            System.out.println(d.substring(0, i));
        }
    };

    biconsumer.accept("Test", "Testing123");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 100 bytes

```
n;f(char*c,char*s){n=strlen(c);while(n)printf("%.*s\n",n--,c);for(n=1;s[n++];)printf("%.*s\n",n,s);}
```

**Ungolfed test**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
n;
f(char*c,char*s)
{
    n=strlen(c);
    while(n)
        printf("%.*s\n",n--,c);
    for(n=1;s[n++];)
        printf("%.*s\n",n,s);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * s1 = "Test";
    char * s2 = "Testing";
    f(s1, s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shared part of two words is not always 1-char long.

Comment: But shrinking ends and expanding begins from the first common character

Comment: Several places to save a few bytes. Make `n` global to make it int implicitly. Convert first `while` to `for` and move `n=strlen(c)` into it to drop a semicolon. Replace second do-while with another `for` and change logic like this: `for(n=1;s[n++];)printf("%.*s\n",n,s);` I've got it down to 99 bytes using similar code.

Comment: @aragaer Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>117</s> 109 bytes

```
for($i=strlen($a=$argv[1]);$i>1;)echo" ".substr($a,0,$i--);
for(;$j<strlen($b=$argv[2]);)echo" ".$c.=$b[$j++];
```

```
for($i=strlen($a=$argv[1]);$i>1;)echo substr($a,0,$i--)." ";
for(;$i<=strlen($b=$argv[2]);)echo substr($b,0,$i++)." ";
```

#### PHP, 107 bytes (not working with strings containing `0`)

```
for($a=$argv[1];$a[$i];)echo substr($a.a,0,-++$i)." ";
for($b=$argv[2];$b[$j];)echo substr($b,0,++$j+1)." ";
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 129 bytes

```
void f(string i, string j){for(int k=i.Length,l=0;i!=j;){Console.Write(i+'\n');i=k>1?i.Remove(--k):i+j[k+l++];}Console.Write(i);}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
void f(string i, string j)
{
   for (int k = i.Length, l = 0; i != j; )
   {
      Console.Write(i+'\n');
      i = k > 1 ? i.Remove(--k) : i + j[k + l++];
   }
   Console.Write(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 120 bytes

```
[](string s,string t){int n=s.length(),k=t.length(),l=n,j=0;s+=t;while(n?n:++j<k)cout<<s.substr(n?0:l,n?n--:1+j)<<endl;}
```

**Ungolfed test**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string s1 = "Test";
    string s2 = "Testing";
    auto f = [](string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.length(), 
            k = t.length(), 
            l = n, 
            j = 0; 
        s += t;
        while (n?n:++j<k)
            cout << s.substr( n?0:l, n?n--:1+j) << endl;
    };
    f(s1, s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## (Lambdabot) Haskell - 41 bytes

```
f=(.drop 2.inits).(++).reverse.tail.inits
```

More readable, but two bytes longer:

```
a!b=(reverse.tail$inits a)++drop 2(inits b)
```

Output:

```
f "Hello" "Hi!"
["Hello","Hell","Hel","He","H","Hi","Hi!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 18 bytes

```
]\@],~[:}:[:|.]\@[
```

Ungolfed:

```
]\@] ,~ [: }: [: |. ]\@[
```

This is a 7-train:

```
]\@] ,~ ([: }: ([: |. ]\@[))
```

The innermost train `[: |. ]\@[` consists of a cap `[:` on the left, so we apply `|.` (reverse) to the result of `]\@[`, which is `]\` (prefixes) over `[` (left argument).

Here's what that looks like on the `testing, test` input:

```
   'testing' ([: |. ]\@]) 'test'
test
tes
te
t
```

This gives us the first portion, almost. The 5-train outside of that is `([: }: ([: |. ]\@[))`, which applies `}:` (betail, remove last element) to the above expression:

```
   'testing' ([: }: [: |. ]\@]) 'test'
test
tes
te
```

(This is because we can't have a duplicate midpoint.)

The outer part is finally:

```
]\@] ,~ ([: }: ([: |. ]\@[))
```

This is composed of `]\@]` (prefixes of left argument) and `,~` (append what's to the left with what's to the right), leaving us with the desired result:

```
   'testing' (]\@] ,~ ([: }: ([: |. ]\@[))) 'test'
testing
testin
testi
test
tes
te
t
te
tes
test
```

### Test cases

```
   k =: ]\@] ,~ ([: }: ([: |. ]\@[))
   'o' k 'o'
o
   k~ 'o'
o
   'test' k 'test'
test
tes
te
t
te
tes
test
   k~ 'test'
test
tes
te
t
te
tes
test
   '. . .' k '...'
. . .
. .
. .
.
.
..
...
   'z' k 'zz'
z
zz
```

Comment: You can rearrange it to 14 bytes using `(,~}:@|.)&(]\)`

Answer (score 1):

## C, 111 bytes

```
f(char*a, char*b){int l=strlen(a),k=1;while(*a){printf("%s\n",a);a[--l]=0;}while(b[k]) printf("%.*s\n",++k,b);}
```

**Ungolfed test**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

f(char*a, char*b) {
  int l=strlen(a), k=1;
  while(*a) {
    printf("%s\n",a);
    a[--l]=0;
  }
  while(b[k])
    printf("%.*s\n",++k,b);
}

int main() {
  char a[10] = {0};
  char b[10] = {0};

  for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    a[i] = 'a' + i;
    b[i] = 'a' + i*2;
  }

  f(&(a[0]), &(b[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck, 162 bytes

```
,[>,]++++++++++[[-<]>[->]<]++++++++++[<[+<]<[+<]>[+>]>[+>]<---]<[<]<[<]>[[.>]++++++++++.----------<[-]<[[->+<]<]>>]>[<+>-]>[[<+>-]<[<]>[.>]++++++++++.---------->]
```

[Try it here](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-LF0rKysrKysrKysrW1stPF0-Wy0-XTxdKysrKysrKysrK1s8Wys8XTxbKzxdPlsrPl0-Wys-XTwtLS1dPFs8XTxbPF0-W1suPl0rKysrKysrKysrLi0tLS0tLS0tLS08Wy1dPFtbLT4rPF08XT4-XT5bPCs-LV0-W1s8Kz4tXTxbPF0-Wy4-XSsrKysrKysrKysuLS0tLS0tLS0tLT5d&input=VGVzdApUZXN0aW5n)

Input takes the two strings separated by a linefeed.

First program with brianfuck and first code golf so I'm sure there is plenty of optimization to be done.  Had fun doing it though.

Ungolfed

```
,[>,] Read all input
++++++++++ Flag for 10
[                   Subtract 10 from each cell to flag space for blank
    [-<]            
    >
        [->]
        <
]
++++++++++ Flag for 10
[                   Add 10 back to each cell with value in it
    <[+<]<[+<]
    >[+>]>[+>]<---
]
<[<]<[<]>               goto first cell in first string string      

[                           Print first word subtracting one each time
    [.>]                    Print first string
    ++++++++++.----------   Print new line
    <[-]                    Kill last letter of first string
    <                       Back one
    [                       Move each first string character up one
          [->+<]
          <
    ]>>
]
>[<+>-]>                    Move to first letter of scond string back one goto second letter
[                               
    [<+>-]                  Move next letter back
    <[<]>                   Move to start of string
    [.>]                    Print string
    ++++++++++.----------   Print new line
    >
]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Impressive first post!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 76 bytes

```python
lambda s,t:'\n'.join(g(s)[:-1]+g(t)[::-1])
g=lambda s:s and[s]+g(s[:-1])or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDoMgEIbn@hSURUgtSTuSuLu5dEMHqkJpFAyQJvXlqad1uu/778/d/I0vZ@9JlU0a5fTsJQpF5Hljc/Z2xhJNAhX8emsvmsSVAGmmy6PMA5K2FwH2YStS50WblPNwCRmLBMGPIURcoG0aqzEtEMHVMI7uDHFl2B7VYPXOC/Cy7MI@ZvIdJGwydui8VBHTlmen2Rsb4dWBiqxC/5Z@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 45 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5.625 bytes

```
¦Ṙ?¦ḢJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqPSIsIiIsIsKm4bmYP8Km4biiSiIsIiIsIlwiVGVzdFwiXG5cIlRlc3RpbmdcIiJd)

### Explained

```
¦Ṙ?¦ḢJ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
¦Ṙ      # ‎⁡[prefixes of the first string] reversed
  ?¦Ḣ   # ‎⁢[prefixes of the second string] with the first prefix removed
     J  # ‎⁣Merged into a single list
# ‎⁤Joined on newlines by the j flag
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 29 bytes

```
/OM!w@On;?$!?/
KMd!h.$t..wKh\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/f31ex3ME/z9peRdFen8vbN0UxQ0@lRE@v3Dsj5v///x6pOTn5igpWmv89MnUUMvLLFRKLUhUq80vtAQ)

```
/MM!w.Ot;.$K?h!w?.n$@h!dOK    Full program untangled
/MM                           Puts the two arguments as strings on the stack
   !                          Pops the second string and save it on the tape
    w    .$K                  While the string still have characters
     .O                       Print the string
       t;                     Remove the last character from the string
                              First string done, now second one
                              As the first letter is the same:
            ?                 Get the string from the tape
             h!               Keep the first character on the stack, save the rest on the tape
               w?.n$@    K    While there are still characters to read on the tape
                     h!       Get the first character, put the rest on the tape
                       dO     Join the stack into a new string and print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo)](https://raku.org), 56 bytes

```perl
{join "\n",reverse([\~] $^a.comb),([\~] $^b.comb)[1..*]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMGy3EoFtTTbpaUlaboWNy2qs_Iz8xSUYvKUdIpSy1KLilM1omPqYhVU4hL1kvNzkzR1YPwkCD_aUE9PK7YWon-3NVdxYqVCmoZSSGpxiZKOApjOzEtX0rSGqFiwAEIDAA)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 99 bytes

```
param($a,$b)if($a-eq$b){$a;exit}$a.length..1|%{-join$a[0..--$_]};1..($b.length-1)|%{-join$b[0..$_]}
```

Straightforward. Loops downward through the first string `$a`, then loops upward through the second string `$b`. Has some additional logic at the start where if the strings are equal, so that it only outputs once then `exit`s. The loop indices are off from each other to account for fenceposting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can beat a few with Groovy here...

## Groovy (96 Bytes)

```
def x(a,b,c){(a..b).each{println c.substring(0,it)}};{y,z->x(y.length(),1,y);x(1,z.length(),z);}
```

Try it:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5190971159478272

Explanation:

- X is a closure to print the substring from 0 to x from (a to b) for all integers from a to b.
- The second closure passes the first word from it's length to 1 then does the second word in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```
f=(x,y,n=1)=>x||n++<y.length?(x||y.slice(0,n))+`
`+f(x.slice(0,-1),y,n):''
```

**Explanation**

```
f=(x,y,n=1)=>               //Take 2 inputs, initialize n to 1.
  x||n++<y.length?          //Increment n only if x doesn't have a value (short circuit).
  (x||y.slice(0,n))+`       //If x has a value, return it; otherwise, return y sliced.
  `+f(x.slice(0,-1),y,n):'' //Recurse, removing last char of x. No problem if x is empty.
```

**Snippet**

```js
f=(x,y,n=1)=>x||n++<y.length?(x||y.slice(0,n))+`
`+f(x.slice(0,-1),y,n):''

console.log(f('Test','Testing'));
console.log(f('O','O'));
console.log(f('z','zz'));
console.log(f("0123456789", "02468"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 63 bytes

```
->a,b{f=->s{(1..s.size).map{|l|s[0,l]}};puts f[a].reverse+f[b]}
```

It's an anonymous function taking two strings:

```
$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > ->a,b{f=->s{(1..s.size).map{|l|s[0,l]}};puts f[a].reverse+f[b]}["hey","you"]
hey
he
h
y
yo
you
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gura](https://github.com/gura-lang/gura), 115 bytes

```
t(a,b)={c=a.len()-1;for(i in 0..c){print(a[0..(c-i)]);println();}for(i in 1..b.len()-1){print(b[0..i]);println();}}
```

Just discovered this language on Github, it's pretty good !

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>94</strike> 92 bytes

```javascript
(x,y)=>[x,y].map(z=>[...z].map(e=>z.substr(0,Math.abs(i--)||--i)).join`
`,i=x.length).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBDsIgEEDRvcdgNZPAxAvQG7hzZ0xKK6XTIDSFmkp6d2zU1c/7k3mZ1C88ZxXiw9ZBV9jkG3VzO3Knp5mhHCCi8pPVTaG0dikvcJYXk0cyXQJWCvddKUakKXJoT61kvZG3weXx/9rax5Cit@SjgwHE1aYs5DccnECsHw)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 88 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)@()+($a.Length..1|%{-join$a[0..--$_]})+(2..$b.Length|%{-join$b[0..--$_]})|gu
```

Ungolfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($a,$b)
@()+
($a.Length..1|%{-join$a[0..--$_]})+
(1..$b.Length|%{-join$b[0..--$_]})|
gu

}

@(
    ,('O', 'O', 'O')
    ,('Test', 'Testing', 'Test Tes Te T Te Tes Test Testi Testin Testing')
    ,('Hello!', 'Hi.', 'Hello! Hello Hell Hel He H Hi Hi.')
    ,('z', 'zz', 'z zz')
    ,('.vimrc', '.minecraft', '.vimrc .vimr .vim .vi .v . .m .mi .min .mine .minec .minecr .minecra .minecraf .minecraft')
) | % {
    $a, $b, $e = $_
    $r = &$f $a $b
    "$r"-eq"$e"
    $r
    ''
}
```

Test script output:

```powershell
True
O

True
Test
Tes
Te
T
Te
Tes
Test
Testi
Testin
Testing

True
Hello!
Hello
Hell
Hel
He
H
Hi
Hi.

True
z
zz

True
.vimrc
.vimr
.vim
.vi
.v
.
.m
.mi
.min
.mine
.minec
.minecr
.minecra
.minecraf
.minecraft
```

Expalantion:

The sum of arrays puts by pipes to `gu` (alias for [Get-Unique](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Unique)). The `gu` eliminates double strings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 65 bytes

```forth
: f dup 1 do 2dup cr type 1- loop 2drop 1 do dup cr i type loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBDoAgDATAu6/YcMdEj/oNP2AQkEQsKWji6xGUU7c7TQ1x2qU1deQ8wWC7AgZshLEmxUhP0BgkDqJQSqbmjd1/8Omco8CiY3KnFWhZlKeKu7L13p1a8WrSh/3tPKvC@QU)

Takes arguments in order on the stack (will look like reverse order in code)

#### Explanation

Loops from  1 to string1-length outputting the increasingly smaller string each time. Then loops from 1 to string2-length + 1, outputting the increasingly larger string each time

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                    \ begin word definition
  dup 1 do             \ duplicate the string length, then loop from 1 to string-length
    2dup               \ duplicate string address and length
    cr type            \ output a newline, then print the word to the given length
    1-                 \ subtract 1 from string length
  loop                 \ end the loop
  2drop                \ drop address and string length of first string
  1 do                 \ loop from 1 to string2-length
    dup                \ duplicate string address
    cr i type          \ output a new line then print the first i characters of the string
  loop                 \ end the loop
;                      \ end the string definition
```