# Character by Character

Tags: code-golf, string

Your program must take in a string like:

```
test string
```

And must output each character adding one at a time like this:

```
t
te
tes
test
test 
test s
test st
test str
test stri
test strin
test string
```

notice how spaces count!

Good luck!
Least Bytes win.
~N

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/92168/42963).

Comment: Is a trailing new line at the end acceptable?

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This is a nice first challenge :). Unfortunately this has been done before and is therefore a duplicate :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
j._
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j._&input=%27test+string%27&debug=0).

```
j       Join by newlines
 ._     all prefixes of implicit input
```

Comment: You should accept Emigna's answer, because it also has 3 bytes and was posted earlier

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
.p»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnDCuw&input=dGVzdCBzdHJpbmc)

**Explanation**

```
     # implicit input
.p   # list of prefixes
  »  # join by newlines
```

Comment: Wow! Only 3 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
"GX@:)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkdYQDop&input=J3Rlc3Qgc3RyaW5nJw)

```
         % Implicit input
"        % For each
  G      %   Push input again
  X@:    %   Push [1 2 ... k] where k is iteration index
  )      %   Use as index into the string
         % End for each
         % Implicit display
```

Comment: Nice job! Do I update the winner as new code is posted?

Comment: Usually we wait for about a week until accepting an answer as winner

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
@[@w\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QFtAd1w&input=InRlc3Qgc3RyaW5nIg)

Assuming that a trailing new line is acceptable

#### Explanation

```
@[       Take a prefix of the Input
  @w     Write it to STDOUT followed by a linebreak
    \    False: try another prefix of the input
```

Comment: A trailing new line is fine.